# parse the html using jsoup

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I have an html code to parse using Jsoup:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <body class="show">
    <div class="page show">
      <div class="content-wrapper posting-page">
        <div class="content">
          <div class="section-wrapper accent-section page-full-width">
            <div class="section section page-centered posting-header">
              <div class="posting-headline">
                <h2>Algorithms Engineer</h2>
                <div class="posting-categories">
                </div>
                <div class="postings-btn-wrapper">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="section-wrapper page-full-width">
                <div class="section section page-centered">
                  <p></p>
                  <div>
                    <span style="font-size: 14.6667px">Do you eat combinatorial optimization for breakfast? Yum!</span>
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    <br>
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    <span style="font-size: 14.6667px">As an on-demand valet service, Luxe is in the business of deciding who will do what, when, and where. Our logistics engine is built on clever algorithms spanning Optimization, Graph Theory, Markov Chains, and Machine Learning.</span>
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    <br>
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    <p></p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="section section page-centered">
                    <div>
                      <h3>Qualifications:</h3>
                      <ul class="posting-requirements plain-list">
                        <ul>
                          <li>PhD in Computer Science, Operations Research, Applied Math, or equivalent</li>
                          <li>3+ years in a fast-moving, product-driven company</li>
                          <li>History of accomplishment and achievement in the field</li>
                          <li>Advanced facility with Python, plus whatever languages best run your algorithms</li>
                          <li>Respect for “good enough” over “perfect”</li>
                          <li>Healthy detachment from your code</li>
                        </ul>
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="section page-centered last-section-apply">
                    <a class="postings-btn template-btn-submit" href="https://jobs.lever.co/luxe/f0418d22-2c3f-4c2d-a53f-dbbb8baff424/apply">Apply for this job</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="main-footer page-full-width">
              <script async="" src="//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js">
                < script data - releasestage = "production"
                data - endpoint = "https://bugs.lever.co/js"
                data - appversion = "0.0.1489100506"
                data - apikey = "6a247c6ff13012d02fde17377f0b857b"
                src = "/js/bug-snag.js" >
                  <
                  script >
                  <
                  script >
                  <
                  /body> <
                  /html>
```

I want to get all the text inside class "section section page-centered" be it be `<span>` message or be it be `<ul>`. 
I need to get the whole text, can anyone help me in doing this.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
Document doc2 = Jsoup.connect("your web page").get();
Elements ele = doc.getElementsByClass("section.section.page-centered").not("section.section.page-centered.posting-header");
String text = ele.text();
//ele.text() gives the only the text
```